# Change color of trace in subplot on condition Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I'm trying to change the color of a subplot trace on a condition but am having trouble with changing individual plots, I've added the conditions into a loop where I'm looping through the axes. Though it is only applying the color to the last trace.

This is my code:

```
# import pandas as pd
# import numpy as np
# import seaborn as sn
#create dataframe 
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 200)
data = {'PTID': [11111, 11111,],
        'Period' : ['Baseline','p3'] ,    
        'ALK PHOS': [46.0, 94.0,],
        'AST (SGOT)': [73.0, 32.0,],
        'Saturation- Iron': [34.0, 65.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#melt into long format 
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['PTID','Period'], var_name='Metric',value_name='Value')

#get average of data for period
dfg = dfm.groupby(['PTID','Period', 'Metric'])['Value'].mean().reset_index()

#drop periods in between, only keep first and last 
dfd = dfm[dfm['Period'].isin(['Baseline','p3'])]

#create dataframe with % difference between periods 
dfdg = dfd.groupby(['Metric', 'Period'])['Value'].mean().reset_index()
dfp = pd.pivot(dfdg, values='Value', index=['Metric'],
                    columns=['Period']).reset_index()

dfp['Difference'] = ((dfp['p3'] - dfp['Baseline'])/dfp['Baseline'])*100
dfp = dfp.round(2)
print(dfp)
#plot subplots
g = sns.relplot(data=dfd, col='Metric', x='Period', y='Value', hue = 'PTID',kind='line', col_wrap=5, marker='o', palette='tab10',facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True},)

dfp.sort_values(by=['Metric'])
#add % change text to subplots 
for ax, row in zip(g.axes.flat,dfp['Difference']):
    if row < 0:
            col = 'r'
    else:
            col = 'g'
    ax.text(0.75,0.75, str(row) + "%",fontsize=12,transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Is there something I can add in this loop, similar to the code to add text `ax.text(0.75,0.75, str(row) + "%",fontsize=12,transform=ax.transAxes)`, that will allow me to control the color of the lines in the relplot based on the `if/else` statement?

```
#add % change text to subplots 
for ax, row in zip(g.axes.flat,dfp['Difference']):
    if row < 0:
            col = 'r'
    else:
            col = 'g'
    ax.text(0.75,0.75, str(row) + "%",fontsize=12,transform=ax.transAxes)
```

So far I haven't been able to find any similar examples.

Comment: `lineplot` accepts "palette" as a kwarg. You could try that: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot

Comment: Your call to `g.map(sns.lineplot,...)` redraws all lines again and again.  Note that a line can only have one color. You'd need to draw individual segments (your rows seem to be points, not line segments).

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, that I kinda get. I just can't find a method to apply the colors to individual subplots and this was the best example I could come up with.

Comment: Maybe you want `for ax, row in zip(...):` followed by `sns.lineplot(...., ax=ax)`? That way, you only change one subplot at a time.  With  `g.map` you change all subplots.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, this is helpful. Though not quite what I need. I've reworded my question a little to better reflect what I'm trying to do. Which is control the colors of the lines in the relplot based on a condition. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: `hue` is meant to change the color depending on a condition.  As a line can only have one color, there is only one `hue`

Comment: Thanks, so far I've only seen examples of ```hue``` changing based on a set of variables in the dataset. IDs for example. What I'm trying do du is change the color of the line based on whether or not the value is above or below 0. To denote a positive or negative change. Surprisingly to me, I can't find any examples of this being done before...

Comment: You could add a new column, e.g. `dfp['Positive'] = dfp['Difference'] >= 0` and use that for hue,